# why 'print' can give an exact value while other are not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

```
def fc_range(start, end, step=1.0):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start +=step
for x in fc_range(0, 1, 0.05):
    print x # look the ans
print list(fc_range(0, 1, 0.05)) # compare the ans now
```

and when I test this:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.05
0.15000000000000002
```

it seems like to be clear, but why when I use `print` the answer is not `0.15000000000000002` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I use print the answer is not 0.15000000000000002"? It is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, floating point maths are not exact because most floating point numbers can NOT be represented exactly with `float`.

As a result, the value of `0.1 + 0.15` are not exactly `0.25`, but some number very close to it.

---

The reason that `print` gives you a seemingly exact result is because, it uses `str` to get the result, which is the user-friendly string representation.

```
>>> str(0.1 + 0.05)
'0.15'
```

The Python interpreter, on the other hand,  uses `repr`, which gives you the as-code string representation:

```
>>> repr(0.1 + 0.05)
'0.15000000000000002'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `print` calls float's `__str__` method under the hood and for some reason `__str__` on floats does rounding.

Comment: You wouldn't really want `__str__` *not* to round, would you? Without any rounding, `1/100.0` would print as `0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375`, for example.

Comment: @MarkDickinson And what is wrong with that? You prefer lie over truth? Implicit rounding is at least confusing. Not to mention that Python is not following its own zen: "explicit is better then implicit".

Comment: What's wrong with it is that it produces an insane number of digits for small or large floats. For example, the true value stored for `1e-300` gives a string of length 756 if written exactly (750 digits, an exponent and a decimal point). So yes, in the spirit of the Zen: "Practicality beats Purity", and it's impractical to show all 750 digits.